# jQuery accordion "heightStyle: fill" with display set to none on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

### My World

- **jQuery 1.9.1**
- **jQuery UI 1.10.3**, although my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8B4W/1/) uses UI 1.9.2 and seems to work fine.

### My Problem

There are many similar questions to this on stackoverflow, but I was unable to find a suitable answer. Basically I've got a jQuery accordion that is not to be displayed when the page loads, and its display can be changed to `block` via the jQuery `.toggle()` method. The toggle works fine, but the `heightStyle: "fill"` does not fill the space appropriately *unless* the parent div is displayed when the page is loaded, which I don't want.

### My Attempts at Solutions

- Repositioning the script at the end of the document and in the `<head>` section.
- Rearranging the order in which the toggle happens: there is a second element, `#map`, which is toggled off at the same time as the accordion is toggled on, and vice versa.
- As I am not entirely sure whether the accordion needs a parent container in the first place, I've tried it several ways: toggling the `#accordion` div, its parent div, and both div's.
- For good measure, I've also attempted the `.accordion( "refresh" )` method, as well as having a resizable container, on both the parent div and the `#accordion`. No soup.
- Various CSS positioning for the parent container and `#accordion`.
- Getting my hands dirty deep within jQuery.js. Given my fledgling experience with javascript, THAT didn't last long. Seriously, had to look up this thing `===`. :)

### My, THIS is Interesting

When the toggle button is clicked to hide the accordion and show `#map` again, you can see the `heightStyle: "fill"` actually work for a second! I slowed the transition duration in the jsfiddle so that it can be seen more easily.

SO, whatever is enabling the correct height calculation for `heightStyle: "fill"`, that is what I need to have happen all the time. Any suggestions appreciated!

**js fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y8B4W/1/

### HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="page-header">
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
  </div>
  <div id="leftpanel">
    <div id="accordion">
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <div>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
      <!-- ...repeat for three more headings/sections... -->
    </div><!--accordion-->
  </div><!-- #leftpanel -->
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #000;
}
.page-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    background: gray;
}
#menu {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#leftpanel {
    display: none;
    background: blue;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#map {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "fill",
    collapsible: true
});
$( "#menu" ).click(function() {
    $( "#map" ).toggle({
        duration: 2000
    });
    $( "#leftpanel" ).toggle({
        duration: 2000
    });
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
});
```

Comment: I might be looking at the wrong thing man, but it works fine for me using Chrome. +1 for nice and organized question.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I am in Chrome as well, and it is definitely not working. Here is what I want to happen: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MHrZ3/). See how the accordion content fills the whole div and there's no white space below the fourth header?

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/sNdFj/

Comment: Thanks for the input. Looks like you put everything into a function, and moved the 'refresh' above the toggles. Unfortunately this results in the calculation of the parent height being too large rather than too small (like I had in my example). I did figure a workaround, which I will post soon. It's more of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a cheap and cheeky hack, but it works. Basically the height of the parent div, `#leftpanel`, was not being calculated correctly when the page loaded (which is when jQuery assigns the accordion's height) because of its `display:none` property. SO, I just grabbed the height myself and assigned it to `#accordion` manually before the accordion functionality is even added, which works like a dream:

```
$( "#menu" ).click(function() {
    $( "#map" ).toggle( "slow" );
    if ($( "#leftpanel" ).css("display") == "none") {
        $(function() {
            $( "#leftpanel").css("display", "block");
            var accordHt = $( "#leftpanel" ).css( "height" );
                $( "#accordion").css("height", accordHt);
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                heightStyle: "fill",
                collapsible: true
            });
       });
    };
});
```

And if you're wondering why the 'if' statement instead of just assigning the property outright, it's because of a media query in which I have `#leftpanel` being displayed when the page loads on screen widths 800px and up.

Go ahead, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72rw2/

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to call a refresh after `display:none` changes.

```
$( "#menu" ).click(function() {
    $( "#leftpanel").css("display", "block");
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
}
```